# Override uri_protocol on specific controller in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, oauth, authorization

I need to override the uri_protocol which is in config file for some controllers in CodeIgniter. I need to change it to "PATH_INFO" since i am using Oauth 2.0,the authorization code is returned via query string.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work? What were the errors?

Comment: I if set 'PATH_INFO' in config file, all urls are redirected to homepage.I think it may lead me in some problem because site is in Live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Query string worked by adding the line to the config file,

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```